# Shouldn't there be a specific Wayland ATI driver?

Tags: drivers, xorg, ati, fglrx, wayland

I use a 1Gb ATI HD Radeon Graphic card on a Dell Laptop

I'm still a newbee at this; But from my understanding, the latest Ubuntu does not use X.org anymore, but uses Wayland. And the fglrx (both the one provided by canonical, and the one you can download from the amd site itslef) are used for X.org. I've managed to get both of them working in the latest Ubuntu (since the GL Billards game seems to work fine). But shouldn't there specifically be a Wayland ATI Driver?

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu still uses X.org (and will do so in 12.04, too).

Answer (score 3):

As said [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/11561/18612), NVIDIA has stated they do not currently plan on supporting Wayland, and I'd suspect ATI to have a similar stance even if they have not made an announcement about it. Wayland is still well off in the future at this point, and it would take the proprietary graphics vendors a while to rewrite their drivers to support a brand-new display manager for an OS that doesn't have a lot of market share yet.

I don't know how current open-source driver support is for Wayland, but I think it'd be safe to assume that an open-source Wayland driver will appear much sooner than a proprietary one.

Answer (score 2):

I can understand you confusion due to recent news items etc, but Ubuntu does not use Wayland yet, and probably will not for a while.

That being said, the way how wayland is built, there will probably not be a need for a specific "wayland" driver.

Comment: That is interesting. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Modern Graphic Drivers, which utilize KMS, are expected to work in Wayland without a complete rewrite.  The problem is because the proprietary drivers, have not even switched to KMS.  The graphic venders, which provide proprietary drivers, are always behind the devs.  They always say, "we wont be supporting 'X' new feature".  Eventually pressure builds, and they support the new feature.  A good example was in relation to AIGLX support, and now still with lacking VAAPI support.