# xdotool not working after Ubuntu 17.10 upgrade

Tags: 17.10, wayland, xdotool

This is my first day after upgrading from 17.04 to 17.10. I've noticed that `xdotool` is not working as it used to. For example:

`xdotool type "Lorem ipsum"` types nothing.

`xdotool key ctrl+shift+t` doesn't open a new tab in gnome-terminal.

`xdotool mousemove 0 0` doesn't move the mouse.

`xdotool click 1` doesn't click on the stuff under the mouse.

`xdotool getactivewindow windowmove 100 100` doesn't move the active window and returns an error:

```
XGetWindowProperty[_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW] failed (code=1)
xdo_get_active_window reported an error
```

What I found is still working:

`xdotool search --classname Navigator windowactivate` does activate the browser.

`xdotool getmouselocation --shell` returns info about mouse position.

`xdotool selectwindow` does allow me to click on a window to get its id.

I have some scripts that rely on this tool. Any suggestion how to fix this?

UPDATE: I'm using Wayland display manager. Switching to Xorg makes it work again. Is it possible to make xdotool work again while still using Wayland?

Comment: Wayland? Try to [switch back to Xorg](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10).

Comment: Yeah... Following your suggestion, it works. Thanks!

Comment: No workaround for wayland? I've read it is [better than xorg](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11537/why-is-wayland-better)

Comment: You want a workaround to get xdotool to work in Wayland? AFAIK, that won't be possible. `man xdotool` has this: xdotool lets you programatically (or manually) simulate keyboard input and mouse activity, move and resize windows, etc. It does this using X11's XTEST extension and other Xlib functions.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a discrete graphics card? if so, try using a different graphics driver.

I recently had a similar error on a clean install of Ubuntu. `xdotool` didn't seem to work, when it was definitely working on previous installations (They had been upgrades - but I wanted a fresh, clean install.)

I found that switching to the **latest proprietary graphics** drivers fixed my issue. The open source driver might handle synthesised input in a different way to the proprietary one.