# Is there any way to create shortcuts to open specific section of top panel

Tags: 20.04, shortcut-keys, panel, top-bar

I know that I can use `ctrl+alt+shift+tab` to go to the top panel. But I want to create a keyboard shortcut to trigger sections of it (for example the top-right menu in the panel). Is there any way for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shortcut keys to open sections of the top panel include

**Activities**

Next to simply pressing <kbd>Super</kbd>, you can open the Activities overview with the shortcut keys <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. There is also <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> to immediately display the Application overview.

**Application menu**

The application menu, i.e. the button with the icon and name of your application, can be opened with <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>.

**Calendar/notifications**

Use <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> or <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to open the calendar panel.

**User menu**

Somewhat surprising, no shortcut key is available by default to open the User menu at the right with the keyboard. Still, Gnome Shell can be controlled over dbus. Either of the following commands will pull down the User menu. Select one and bind it to a shortcut key using "Settings" - "Keyboards Shortcuts".

```
gdbus call -e -d org.gnome.Shell -o /org/gnome/Shell -m org.gnome.Shell.Eval string:'Main.panel.statusArea.aggregateMenu.menu.toggle();'
```

or

```
dbus-send --session --type=method_call --dest=org.gnome.Shell /org/gnome/Shell org.gnome.Shell.Eval string:'Main.panel.statusArea.aggregateMenu.menu.open();'
```

Answer (score 0):

The below command in a terminal opens the menu in Question.

```
dbus-send --session --type=method_call --dest=org.gnome.Shell /org/gnome/Shell org.gnome.Shell.Eval string:'Main.panel.statusArea.aggregateMenu.menu.open();'
```

you can bind it to keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

This did work me me, in a script, with a custom keyboard shortut to run it.. though now, with a new Ubuntu and fresh install of xdotool it is not working, mouse does not move. ... but this is the idea.  on a 1920X1080 resolution....

> xdotool mousemove 1910  16 && xdotool click 1

Comment: ahh, does not work in wayland...  see https://askubuntu.com/questions/969874/xdotool-not-working-after-ubuntu-17-10-upgrade and , contrary to the last answer there, I am using proprietary NVIDIA drivers.

Comment: you can get your coordinates with xdotool getmouselocaton at the top left where you would click