# How to disable Wayland/Libinput software mouse buttons?

Tags: mouse, touchpad, thinkpad, wayland, libinput

with Ubuntu 17.10 I am new to Wayland. I understand [it's advantageous](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11537/why-is-wayland-better) and really want to give it a chance. However, the libiput software buttons are killing me.

Due to the hardware buttons on top, the physical Touchpad is limited in space (5.5 x 10 cm). Now Waylands Libinput is emulating another bar of mouse buttons in the lower 10mm (documented [here](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/clickpad_softbuttons.html#clickfinger)).

[image]

As I love the physical layout of the touchpad I would like to disable the software buttons. Does anyone know how to do so?

Answer (score 0):

The relevant option for configuring click behavior is called [`click_method`](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/configuration.html#click-method) in libinput. The default value of "button areas" will use the software button zone.

You can change this parameter to "clickfinger" if you prefer the Apple-style behavior of treating a two-finger click or tap as a right click, and a three-finger click or tap as a middle click.
Alternatively, you can set this to none if you prefer to use only hardware buttons.

The means of configuring this option will be different for each desktop environment. In GNOME, the setting corresponds to the `gsettings` path of `org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad`, and you could change it like so:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad click-method 'fingers'
```