# Can't login with my PIN password in Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: login, 18.10

I followed the instructions in [How to set a PIN password or a short password in Ubuntu Linux](http://blog.radevic.com/2017/11/how-to-set-pin-password-or-short.html)  to make my life easier, 
but apparently it didn't made my life any easier:

Now I can't login to my Ubuntu 18.10 desktop environment even with my own PIN password that I set up.

*what should I do now?*

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: I can't login even with my own password, "pin that I set up using that instructions."

Comment: But the image you posted has nothing to do with the problem you are describing... it is just a wizard to select your display manager (X11 vs Wayland).
https://askubuntu.com/questions/11537/why-is-wayland-better

Comment: Whole point I can't login, I know it's sounds annoying but is there any default password or something like that!?

Comment: I found it.I followed this instructions: http://blog.radevic.com/2017/11/how-to-set-pin-password-or-short.html what am I missing here?!

Comment: Those instructions look old, many things have changed since version 16.04. You can try CTRL+ALT+F1 to login with your regular password into a console then uninstall the package that you are using for the pin-thing (sudo apt remove libpam-pwdfile)

Comment: You can check your password by logging in via a text terminal.  If however you don't have enough space in $HOME (your user directory), a gui login will fail and you will be logged out & be asked to login again (gui requires temporary work files to be created & used, and can't proceed if space is limited; text login does not require this).   By logging in via text terminal, you can confirm your password, then check you have space (`df -hl` or disk-free -human.output+local only)

Comment: When and how many times I should press CTRL+ALT+F1 ?

Comment: As soon as you get some UI graphics (other than the initial "loading" screen) showing up, you should be able to do CTRL+ALT+F1. Doing it once should be enough. Good luck.

Comment: Ok, I have uninstalled/purged both "libpam-pwdfile" and "lightdm". Now how to switch back to GUI version. After reboot, I get terminal mode only.

Comment: Matter is solved now. Thanks u yms and guivrec. I also used stackflow to reinstall default display manager. Thanks again.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! If you solved your own problem, please consider to [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) one it it reopened and accept your answer. Don’t put the answer in your question or the comments! :-)

Answer (score 3):

The instructions in the tutorial that you followed are out-of-date because the default login display manager in Ubuntu 18.10 is gdm3, not lightdm. Uninstall the packages that you installed by following the instructions from [How to set a PIN password or a short password in Ubuntu Linux](http://blog.radevic.com/2017/11/how-to-set-pin-password-or-short.html), and reinstall the default login display manager (*gdm3*).

Access a virtual console by pressing the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> from the screen where the system is stopped when trying to boot the computer.

To login from a virtual console:

1. At the `login:` prompt type your username and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
2. At the `Password:` prompt type your user password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. After you have logged in, you can run commands from the virtual console.

Run the following commands.

```
sudo apt purge libpam-pwdfile lightdm    
sudo apt install gdm3   
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3    
sudo reboot
```

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3` will open up a new window allowing you to select gdm3 as the default login display manager. Use the arrow keys to select gdm3 and press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to put the focus on **<OK>** and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Then reboot by running this command: `sudo reboot`