# What is wayland and how do I enable it?

Tags: 20.04, gnome-shell-extension, wayland, extension

What is Wayland and how do I enable it? One extension that I installed said that it needs Wayland to work... Sorry if this is a stupid question. I am new to Ubuntu and the world of Coding. (I haven't even entered it. Still at the door... thinking and exploring...)

Comment: I'm of the opinion that will help, Ubuntu 17.10 defaulted to logging in with Wayland by default (for new installs) where as subsequent releases went back to Xorg by default.

Comment: Also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/11537/why-is-wayland-better